# Adding data to a specific row in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a SQLite database and i need to insert some data on a specific line (on the line from the adapter position) and after to retrieve it.
Can you guys tell me how to add the data on the specific row?

This is my code for SQLITE db:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "event_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "event";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item);

    Log.d(TAG, "addData: Adding " + item + " to " + TABLE_NAME);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns all the data from database
 * @return
 */
public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;
}
}
```

Comment: You either want to `INSERT` a *different* row OR `UPDATE` an *existing* one. These sentences are **mutually exclusive**. Which one is true?

Comment: Insert on a different row something like this : adapter position = 39 so i want that on the row 39 to insert some data

Comment: Is there already a "row 39"? If so, it already has data. So, you want to `UPDATE` the existing data. If the row does not exist, you want to `INSERT` a new row. And you're not granted it will have 39 as its ID, unless you force it manually (which is a terrible table design).

Comment: yeah i know but i made different and now it works and ps i wanted to insert even if there isn.'t data until row 39 :)) (i know i suck at these things :D)

Comment: You should really dive into RDBMS a lot more. To give your users a better experience. If it "somehow works" NOW, it's not said it will keep working when things will get more complicated: you'll add some features, need more tables as well and will arrive to a point where everything will blow up due to a poor design.

Comment: now i have something like this: i press a button it creates a new row whit  name and id and if i want to search for the id i symple search the name :) it's far more better than searching for the adapter position and forcing on a specific line

Comment: Working without a primary key may work for the next weeks. But one day you will regret this (wrong) approach.

Comment: @KlingKlang But i have COL1 whit primary key but i search after COL2 values

Comment: If COL1 was a primary key, then you could not forcefully insert it manually. It's autogenerated.

Comment: Yeah i know but when i start doing something i have bad ideas but after i start working i have better ideas and my habit lead to post this question :D